# Как можно оптимизировать окно при ресайзе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Сделал на питоне простенькое первое приложение, всё бы отлично, но нагружена функция `resizeEvent` и из-за этого при масштабировании окна оно притормаживает, дело в том, что в этой функции такой код:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    self.lbl.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height()))
    self.lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/background.png").scaled(self.width(), self.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                                       transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

для примера показываю только первые 2 строки, дальше они повторяются 12 раз, соответственно именно это замедляет ресайз. Можно ли как то по другому растягивать изображение под размер окна? Так же в конце вызывается функция `onActivated()` которая проверяет в каком состоянии чекбокс и делает своё дело:

```
def onActivated(self):
    if self.check1.isChecked():
        self.lbl1.show()
    else:
        self.lbl1.hide()
```

Так же кусок кода повторяется 12 раз, под каждый label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не работал с pyqt, но из общих соображений есть предположение, что вот эта строка

```
self.lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/background.png").scaled(self.width(),
                   self.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                   transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

будет каждый раз подгружать с диска файл `/img/background.png` и именно это будет самой проблемной частью процесса, так как чтение с диска гораздо медленнее, чем чтение из оперативной памяти

Попробуйте прочитать файл всего один раз - перед тем, как отрисовать этот элемент впервые и сохранить это в аттрибут:

```
self.pixmap = QPixmap(":/img/background.png")
```

а потом при каждом ресайзе делать так:

```
self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(self.width(),
                   self.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                   transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

Comment: Да, действительно, самый очевидный вариант упустил, стало полегче, но всё равно есть некоторая задержка несущественная, буду думать как обернуть все изображения в один лейбл или что-то вроде, думаю поможет